# Why my anchor link from a secoundary page is not working?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have the following problem with one of my current projects.

I would like to achieve that when you click on a link which is on a secondarly page, it sends you to the home page but, not at the top of the homepage (by default), I would like that it sends you where a specific ID is.

At the moment I have the following URL in this special link but it doesn't work

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/index.html#hcontact-anchor"> link </a>
```

I have tried different ways I saw in this community but I didn't have luck. At the moment when you click it send you to the homepage but at the top and my ID is almost at the end of the page

How can I fix it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below code on page load. make sure you call this once DOM is loaded. This will scroll the page to this anchor.

```
location.hash = "#contact-anchor";
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you quick replay. 

Should I change my current <a> for this? 
<a href="location.hash = "#contact-anchor""> link </a>